# Java String Comparison: style choice or optimization?

Tags: java, optimization, gwt, coding-style

I've been taking a look at some GWT code written by various people and there are different ways of comparing strings.  I'm curious if this is just a style choice, or if one is more optimized than another:

```
"".equals(myString);

myString.equals("");

myString.isEmpty();
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: Are you asking just about comparing *empty* strings against string references, or string literals and string references in general?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
"".equals(myString);
```

will not throw a `NullPointerException` if `myString` is null.  That is why a lot of developers use this form.

```
myString.isEmpty();
```

is the best way if `myString` is never null, because it explains what is going on.  The compiler may optimize this or `myString.equals("")`, so it is more of a style choice.  `isEmpty()` shows your intent better than `equals("")`, so it is generally preferred.

Comment: You're correct about "".equals(myString), of course, but I find that this intentionally backward syntax hurts my eyes. I think that if your code runs into a situation where you can't be sure if a String value isn't null, chances are there's an underlying logic problem being plastered over.

Comment: @Carl I find the double quotes outside of the parenthesis look better. But absolutely say NPE to nulls early and often.

Comment: isEmpty() is much more efficient as it only test the string length against 0, while equals involves casting, comparing hash codes and so on. See http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 5):

Beware that `isEmpty()` was added in Java 6, and, unfortunately, there are still people who complain pretty loudly if you don't support Java 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

apache StringUtils provides some convenience methods for, well, String manipulation.

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.CharSequence)

check out that method and associated ones.

Comment: Is `isEmpty` not enough for you?

Comment: why'd vote me down brah?  I mean, the advantage of the StringUtils is that you add consistency to your code so you dont have "".equals(blah) vs blah.equals("").

Comment: @Tom Well, `StringUtils` methods are null safe.

Comment: right on, i dont see why i got a downvote for suggesting an api that is well known, respected, and provides some consistency to these things, simple though they are :(

Comment: @hvgotcodes this is how SO works, stupid people have the same voting power as smart people

Answer (score 0):

myString.isEmpty() is probably best if you are working on a recent version of Java (1.6). It is likely to perform better than myString.equals("") as it only needs to examine one string.

"".equals(myString) has the property of not throwing a null pointer exception if myString is null. However for that reason alone I'd avoid it as it is usually better to fail fast if you hit an unexpected condition. Otherwise some little bug in the future will be very difficult to track down.....

myString.equals("") is the most natural / idiomatic approach for people wanting to keep compatibility with older Java versions, or who just want to be very explicit about what they are comparing to.

Answer (score -3):

Both of the options using "" may require the creation of a temporary String object but the .isEmpty() function shouldn't.

If they bothered to put the .isEmpty() function in I say it is probably best to use it!

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the empty string constant wasn't already part of any JRE's intern pool shortly after startup. And once such a constant is used anywhere within a classloader, it stays available until the JVM exits, so I wouldn't be too concerned about a performance hit.

Comment: isEmpty() was added as a convenience method. Before that, you'd had to check the String length against null like this: if (s.length() == 0).